# printPreview landscape mode inC#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, printing, print-preview

How can I set the print Preview and print code to landscape orientation ?

```
 this.printPreviewDialog1.AutoScrollMargin = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            this.printPreviewDialog1.AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            this.printPreviewDialog1.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(700, 600);
            this.printPreviewDialog1.Document = this.printDocument1;
            this.printPreviewDialog1.Enabled = true;
            this.printPreviewDialog1.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("printPreviewDialog1.Icon")));
            this.printPreviewDialog1.Name = "printPreviewDialog1";
            this.printPreviewDialog1.Visible = false;

            // 
            // printDocument1
            // 
            this.printDocument1.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(this.printDocument1_PrintPage_1);
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the language/technology you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This did the trick

```
this.printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't this

```
var doc = new PrintDocument();
doc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

do the trick?

It will probably take care of the print preview issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```